# Rinsim: Changing the range of a CommDevice

Tags: java, rinsim

Is there a possibility to change the range of a CommDevice? We would like to broadcast a message with a small range and gradually expand the range when no response is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of a `CommDevice` is meant to model the physical limitations of a communication device. The current implementation assumes that these limitations cannot change over time.

The best way of implementing the behaviour that you want is to implement an additional method for broadcasting in [CommDevice](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/rinde/rinsim/core/model/comm/CommDevice.java#L187):

```
public void broadcast(MessageContents contents, double range){ 
  checkRegistered();
  // construct a predicate based on 'range' and 'rangePredicate' (if it exists)
  outbox.add(Message.createBroadcast(user, contents, predicate));
}
```

If you want, you can send a pull request, I will accept it if it is well tested.